# how to deploy .net project to PDA casio device

Tags: visual-studio-2005, windows-ce, device

My project is in visual studio 2005 and i have PDA Casio device.I would like to deploy my dotnet project on my device(PDA CASIO). I have installed required window embedded CE 6.0.

As i am new in these platform ,i tried to add my .net project on sub project of CE emulator (solution emulator),but could not find how to add existing project.Do we need to add project on CE emulator and build it?. I have no idea whether i am heading on right direction.

Can you please give me a suggestion how do i deploy my project to PDA casio device step by step.

And also can you please provide me link(tutorial or ebook) or any resources regarding the same if possible.

Guys, I need you suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not fully clear on your entire question, so I'll throw a broad net to try to get it.

Generally speaking, if you want to create a managed (.NET) application for a Windows CE or Windows Mobile (this does *not* apply to Windows Phone) then you will need to install the following on your PC

- Visual Studio 2005 (Standard or better) or 2008 (Pro or better) to get the Smart Device compilers, templates, etc
- ActiveSync or Windows Mobile Device Center (WMDC), depending on your PC OS
- Possibly a device SDK.  Some SDKs are installed with Studio and I find that they are enough for 99% of devices.

Once you have those installed, create a simple Hello World solution in Studio by selecting one of the "Smart Device" projects in the project creation wizard.  If those are not present, either you don't have the right version of Studio, or they weren't selected to be installed when Studio was installed.

Once you have a Smart Device project created, connect the device to the PC with ActiveSync/WMDC (yes, corecon is an option for a networked device, but just get this working first).

Once connected, change the target device in Visual Studio to point to your device (it typically defaults to an emulator).

Next use F5 to debug - this will deploy the app, the CF and any dependencies and execute in a debug environment.  By default it will put the app in `\Program Files\[your app name]` on the device